# How do I install libtiff.so.3?

Tags: shared-library

When I try to run Maya from the terminal, I get:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libtiff.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

How do I solve this?

Note: Maya is a third-party software.

Comment: Related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tiff/+bug/456257

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the TIFF library. `apt-cache search libtiff` shows packages, you'll need `libtiff4`:

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff4
```

Comment: Why does `libtiff4`provide `libtiff.so.3`?

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功 It does not do that apparently, though in *some* cases you can create a symlink and hope that it works (see sharpzq's answer below).

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure. Because Ubuntu 14.04 provides a libtiff5 which contains libtiff version 4 (there is no version 5 yet).

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功 Ubuntu's libtiff5 package does not contain libtiff.so.4, see the [package list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libtiff5/filelist). There is no libtiff4 package either, see the [source package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/tiff). Perhaps you have a `libtiff4` package from a previous Ubuntu version which remained after upgrade. Check with `dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so` which package the file belongs to and `apt-cache policy libtiff4` where your package comes from.

Answer (score 16):

Repositories for **16.04**, **16.10**, **17.04** and **17.10** have `libtiff5` (most likely included in installation) which provides `libtiff.so.5` but not `libtiff.so.3.` This causes problems for applications that look for `libtiff.so.3` as detailed [in this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tiff/+bug/456257)

First do

```
sudo apt install libtiff5
```

You will likely find it is already installed. However, if not, see if this fixes the problem.

If not, try this workaround: To fool applications into using `libtiff.so.5` instead of `libtiff.so.3`, you can create a symlink in the same directory named `libtiff.so.3` pointing to `libtiff.so.5.` This may not work for all applications, since the libraries are not exactly the same.

To do this in a 32-bit system enter:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.3
```

In a 64-bit system it would be:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.3
```

If unsure, you can find the library on your system like this:

```
locate -b libtiff
```

Then you will be able to get the path correct (if you just installed libtiff5, you have to first do `sudo updatedb` for `locate` to find it)

Comment: Thank you @Zanna.
your solution actually helped me. 

but im getting the another error. 
Maya is crashing while trying to open. I guess it has something to do with my hardware i assume. 
---------------- 

  __libc_start_main
  /usr/autodesk/maya2016/bin/maya.bin() [0x40e06d]

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @HayetMahmud I thought the symlink might have caused the segfault, but looking at your stack trace it appears not... good luck fighting that one =/

Comment: -1 There is a reason why different versions of a library have different file names, as demonstrated by the resulting segfault.

Comment: *shrug* edited to advise that it may not work. However, I think that is the worst that could happen

Answer (score 3):

I'm running in to the same error with a different program.  I'm using Oneiric (Xubuntu 11.10)

```
$ sudo apt-get install libtiff3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libtiff3
```

Libtiff4 is already installed on this system, and clearly doesn't provide `libtiff.so.3`.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libtiff.so.4 /usr/lib/libtiff.so.3
```

I couldn't find `libtiff.so.4` there, but I did find it in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`.   So the command I ran was:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.3
```

And it worked for the game I was trying to play (http://www.happypenguin.org/show?interLOGIC)

Answer (score 1):

If Maya was not built on your machine (i.e. installed from a binary) then you need `libtiff3`, `libtiff4` will not fix your issue as it includes "libtiff.so.4", not "libtiff.so.3". Or you could build Maya from source on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a soft link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libtiff.so.4 /usr/lib/libtiff.so.3
```

Comment: On a 64-bit system you need to do `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4 /usr/lib/libtiff.so.3` instead.

Comment: @N.N. I cant make work even with that. I can install libtiff5 or libtiff4-dev. None of them worked. I've tried most of the command and symbolic links here and still cannot run that. Im looking to run carnival-gui for festival tts.

Answer (score 0):

**Install from source**

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/libtiff/tiff-3.9.6.zip
unzip tiff-3.9.6.zip
cd tiff-3.9.6
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @Downvoters please explain so I can learn an improve. Cheers.