# Static linking to a library

Tags: 12.10, executable, dynamic-linking, libtiff

I'm trying to run a pre-compiled program from

http://cherrypit.princeton.edu/donev/Packing/PackLSD/Instructions.html

The pages states that:

> The executables only link in standard (OpenGL, libtiff, libjpeg, etc.) Linux libraries, and link openglut statically, which may cause failures on some systems. The programs are compiled at medium optimization, for a generic IA32 processor, on a Red Hat EL4 system. They should run on Red Hat (>=9) and Fedora (>=3) systems just fine, and hopefully other similar distributions as well.

A standard Ubuntu  12.10 distribution is unable to run the program with

```
./PackLSD.poly.static.x: error while loading shared libraries: libtiff.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This suggests that I should install the dev versions of libtiff, but neither

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev
sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev
```

seem to help. Am I out of luck getting this program to work without help from the author?

**Edit**: As requested. The output to `sudo dpkg -L libtiff4 libtiff5`

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4.3.6
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libtiff4
/usr/share/doc/libtiff4/README
/usr/share/doc/libtiff4/TODO
/usr/share/doc/libtiff4/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libtiff4/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/libtiff4/copyright
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libtiff4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4

/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5.1.0
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libtiff5
/usr/share/doc/libtiff5/README
/usr/share/doc/libtiff5/TODO
/usr/share/doc/libtiff5/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libtiff5/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/libtiff5/copyright
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libtiff5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install libtiff.so.3?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/44132/how-do-i-install-libtiff-so-3)

Answer (score 1):

You need the library, not the source I believe.

Please do this

`sudo apt-get install libtiff4 libtiff5`

**EDIT:**

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4.3.6 /usr/lib/libtiff.so.3`

This should fix your problem

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this still produces the same error. Does it work on your machine?

Comment: Can you please post the output of `sudo dpkg -L libtiff4 libtiff5`

Comment: Added to output the post.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `ldd PackLSD.poly.static.x` also

Comment: Creating the link now fails with `./PackLSD.poly.static.x: error while loading shared libraries: libtiff.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64`. This is true even when I follow the instructions for the 64-bit version `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4 /usr/lib/libtiff.so.3`.

Comment: That means, we need to install 32 bit version of libtiff.