# I can't install libtiff on my 64-bit Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, apt, software-installation, libtiff

When I try to install `libtiff` on my 64-bit Ubuntu, I get the following error:

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libtiff is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libtiff' has no installation candidate
ubuntu@ip-10-119-97-123:/mnt$ libtiff-memcached

libtiff-memcached: command not found
```

Answer (score 10):

libtiff has no installation candidate. Your choices are:

```
sudo apt install libtiff6
```

for Ubuntu 23.04-24.04 or...

```
sudo apt install libtiff5
```

for Ubuntu 14.04-22.04 or...

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff4
```

for Ubuntu 12.04-13.10

Comment: When I do that it tells me "libtiff5 is already the newest version" but then when look what happens when I  do this: 
>>> from libtiff import TIFF
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'libtiff'

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/732607/libtiff-module-not-found-on-64-bit-ubuntu-14-04-python-3?noredirect=1#comment1087632_732607

Comment: Can I symlink `libtiff4` to `libtiff5`? A program I'm trying to run needs `libtiff4`.

Comment: @AaronFranke https://askubuntu.com/questions/44132/how-do-i-install-libtiff-so-3/786392#786392

Answer (score 4):

If like me, you may be looking for the utils:

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff-tools
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. So what solved it for me was to do:

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

libtiff4 was upto 13.10 and 14.04 provides libtiff5.
To install it nonetheless, go to the download [page](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/) and select [libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb).
Open terminal and, in the folder you downloaded the file, write:

```
sudo dpkg -i libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

libtiff5 and libtiff4 are co-installable, so it will not write over the files of libtiff5.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libtiff4
```

These commands will install libtiff on your 64 bit machine. You can use http://packages.ubuntu.com/ to search for the packages you need. In this case, it is http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libtiff4

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are trying to find a package you don't know a name of but since you already knew something like `libtiff` to try to run

```
`apt-cache search libtiff`
```

or

```
apt-cache search libtiff*
```

This will show you all possible options which you might want to install from, The error no installation candidate simply means that it can't find exact package with that name, so you can search from all the possible packages and get what you want. hope this helps.

If this doesn't work, sure can go for dpkg packages as already shown above.