# Missing shared libraries when using chroot

Tags: 64-bit, lubuntu, libraries, chroot

I'm attempting to use `schroot` to run a 32-bit application on a 64-bit Ubuntu (actually Lubuntu) Raring installation.  I was successful creating the `chroot` populated by the following command:

`sudo debootstrap --arch=i386 raring /srv/chroot/raring_i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`

When I enter the `chroot` environment however and try to start the application I get errors about missing shared libraries.  For example:

> `error while loading shared libraries: libICE.so.s: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

So far all the missing libraries in my `chroot` environment are located at `usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`.  I can copy these missing libraries from a different full installation of 32-bit Ubuntu but I would have thought that the `debootstrap` step above should have downloaded these directly.  Can someone provide some additional insight into how the use of `debootstrap` should create the `chroot` environment?  Have I possibly missed a step or is there a different option in the call to `debootstrap` to tell it to get some additional shared libraries?

Much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of trial/error and lucky web searching I think I found the solution I was looking for.  Here's a summary of the steps I used to solve the issue:

1. Within the `chroot` environment run the following command to reveal the missing libraries:

   ```
   ldd <binary executable>
   ```

   This will reveal missing libraries as "not found".  Alternatively this command can be piped to grep as:

   ```
   ldd <binary executable> | grep "not found"
   ```
2. Use the following command to locate the packages that will supply the missing libraries:

   ```
   apt-cache search <library name>
   ```
3. Install the package from the previous step from within the `chroot` environment (multiple may be found):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install <package name>
   ```

After I repeated the above steps for all missing libraries I was able to successfully launch the application from the `chroot` environment.

The reference I found that gave me the clue to search and install missing libraries is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44132/how-do-i-install-libtiff-so-3).