# Missing libtiff.so.3 when running TrackVis

Tags: libtiff

I downloaded TrackVis and the Diffusion toolkit and I installed all correctly in Ubuntu 12.04. The problem is when I try to launch the program; the following error appears:

```
./trackvis: error while loading shared libraries: libtiff.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Could you help me?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/44132/how-do-i-install-libtiff-so-3